# Header Component Opening MdDialog but need MdDialog to emit an event to tell Header to close the MdDialg

Tags: angular, angular-material2, mddialog

I have a header in my app that has a dropdown menu.  When you click "email" a MdDialog pops up because I have this.dialog.open(EmailDialogComponent).  Works great!  Now I need to click an X in the top right hand of the MdDialog which should emit an event that the header template can listen for and then run

`this.dialog.closeAll()`

I've tried to listen to the event right on the template for the EmailDialogComponent but it still doesn't "hear the event".

I have @Outup closeDialog = new EventEmitter();
Then I have (click)="closeEmailDialog()" on the X.
closeEmailDialog is this
    `closeEmailDialog() {
        this.closeDialog.emit(null);
    }`

But this isn't working.  Even when I listen for the event on the MdDialog template it doesn't appear to be firing - any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your comment not able to understand the full code and what you missed.

Please refer my plunker and understand `EventEmitter` for component communication in angular.

https://plnkr.co/edit/zesHjCIhSjt1TxhpVdeT?p=preview

**Open dialog**

```
 @Component({
  selector: 'dialog-result-example',
  templateUrl: 'dialog-result-example.html',
})
export class DialogResultExample {
  selectedOption: string;

  constructor(public dialog: MdDialog) {}

  openDialog() {
    const dialog = this.dialog.open(DialogResultExampleDialog);
    const sub = dialog.componentInstance.formSubmit$.subscribe(() => {
      alert('hi');
    });
    dialog.afterClosed().subscribe(() => {
      sub.unsubscribe();
    });
  }
}
```

**Close Dialog**

```
 @Component({
  selector: 'dialog-result-example-dialog',
  templateUrl: 'dialog-result-example-dialog.html',
})
export class DialogResultExampleDialog {

   @Output() formSubmit$: EventEmitter<boolean>;

  constructor(public dialogRef: MdDialogRef<DialogResultExampleDialog>) {
    this.formSubmit$ = new EventEmitter();
  }

  closePop(){
    debugger;
    this.formSubmit$.emit(true);
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: @JamesHandshoe Welcome !!! if it's your answer then plz mark as answer. So any one can refer this.